# Does apache spark has geo awareness?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to choose a topology for apache spark cluster across different sites. Does spark has it's own awareness capabilities?

For example assume a cluster with workers in Oregon and Penang.

Now when submitting an application, which loads data from Oregon processes it and saves it back to Oregon. Will Oregon workers will be preferred (if they are free)?
Haven't found documentation regarding this subject.

Comment: Spark itself isn't geo-aware. i.e. it won't know if you have workers in Oregon and Penang and queue tasks only in Oregon since the data is there. You need to build your cluster such that a particular job runs with workers that have minimum network latency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described here https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-data-locality.html

> Spark relies on data locality, aka data placement or proximity to data
>   source, that makes Spark jobs sensitive to where the data is located.
>   It is therefore important to have Spark running on Hadoop YARN cluster
>   if the data comes from HDFS.
>   The data system may itself be geo-aware e.g. cassandra: [Does Spark use data locality?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27638281/does-spark-use-data-locality) http://www.slideshare.net/RussellSpitzer/spark-cassandralocality